# Element overlaps wrapper 100

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have some simple code and was just wondering why my elements inside of my grid breaks out of it if I have width 100%. I dont have any extra margins or padding on the elements that could make them overexceed the width 100%. When at 922px, a scrollbar appears.

```css
main {
  display: contents;
}

main section {
  background-color: white;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 'section1 section2 section3 section4';
  gap: 2rem;
}

.section1 {
  grid-area: section1;
}

.section2 {
  grid-area: section2;
}

.section3 {
  grid-area: section3;
}

.section4 {
  grid-area: section4;
}

section img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

section p:first-of-type {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

section p {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 901px) and (max-width: 1320px) {
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="content">
    <section class="section1">
      <img src="bilder/gojo.jpg">
      <h2>Victim 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
    </section>

    <section class="section2">
      <img src="bilder/geto.jfif">
      <h2>Victim 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
    </section>
    <section class="section3">
      <img src="bilder/riko.jfif">
      <h2>Victim 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
    </section>
    <section class="section4">
      <img src="bilder/toji.jpg">
      <h2>Victim 4</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet placeat deserunt adipisci magni odit natus optio vel aspernatur cumque possimus praesentium neque maxime mollitia quod omnis fugit, architecto sunt reprehenderit!</p>
    </section>

  </div>
</main>
```

It worked when I removed the gap. However, since my images are set at 200px and 2rem is supposed to be 36px. Adding all the width (200 x 4) + (36 x 3) = 908 is where the scrollbar should appear right?

Comment: you didn't count the body margin (16px)

Comment: I have a css reset so the body margin is set to 0.